# Добавление в закладки javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Сразу говорю не силён в javascript. Нашёл в интернете скрипт для добавления в закладки сайта. Но когда нажимаешь ссылку добавить в закладки почти во всех браузерах выскакивает всплывающее окно с подтверждением добавления в закладки.
Вопрос: Можно ли как нибудь обойти это окно, т.е. чтобы после нажатия на ссылку сайт сразу же добавлялся в закладки?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя.

Comment: @doctorpepper608, Было бы интересно выслушать обоснование.

Comment: запрещено политикой браузера

Comment: ...и здравым смыслом